# Orgmode: how to filter the blocks to be tangle?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

In Orgmode, is there a way to **tangle just the blocks in subtree matching (or not matching) a specific tag**?

For instance with the following code

```
* A
#+BEGIN_SRC c
   printf("Not exported");
#+END_SRC

* B                :D:

#+BEGIN_SRC c
  printf("Exported");
#+END_SRC
```

exporting along tag *D*, the tangle C file will only contains `printf("Exported");`

I'm using `org-mode` to organise my emacs config, and my goal is to *derive different configs* from the master one `emacs-config.org`. (for instance a lightconfig by marking just the specific)

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this behavior you can make use of the fact that aside from `yes` and `no`, the `:tangle` header argument for Org Babel code blocks also [understands file names](http://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-source-code.html); i.e., for any given code block you can tell Org Babel which file you would like the block to be tangled to. My idea is to *automatically set the file name for each code block under a certain headline when adding a tag to the headline*:

```lisp
(defun org-babel-set-tangle-file ()
  (let ((tag (car (org-get-local-tags))))
    (org-narrow-to-subtree)
    (while (re-search-forward "\\(:tangle \\).*" nil t)
      (replace-match (concat "\\1" tag ".el")))
    (widen)))

(add-hook 'org-after-tags-change-hook 'org-babel-set-tangle-file)
```

The resulting behavior is that when you call `org-babel-tangle` for the current file, all code blocks belonging to

- headlines *without* a tag will be tangled to the default tangle file(s)
- a tagged headline will be tangled to a file named after the tag.

Note that the function above sets the file extension of tag-specific tangle files to `.el`; since you mention that you would like to produce different Emacs configurations I figured that would be a reasonable default (even though you are showing C code in your example).

Comment: I've just try but didn't really work as expected.  (since you are excepting that there is :tangle tag, and I prefer not to add the to all the block )
I prefer mike idea to filter the collected block. feels more flexible, and can had more logic behin it

Answer (score 2):

I tried researching this a while ago and found no quick answer.
I ended up modifying `org-babel-tangle-collect-blocks` to implement this functionality

Here is the modified function. The list `org-babel-tags` is a list of ok tags. For your example, you need to set it with `(setq org-babel-tags '("D"))`

(I added the first 4 lines after the first call to 'unless')

```
(defvar org-babel-tags nil
  "only tangle entries that has a tag in this list")

(defun org-babel-tangle-collect-blocks (&optional language)
  "Collect source blocks in the current Org-mode file.
Return an association list of source-code block specifications of
the form used by `org-babel-spec-to-string' grouped by language.
Optional argument LANG can be used to limit the collected source
code blocks by language."
  (let ((block-counter 1) (current-heading "") blocks)
    (org-babel-map-src-blocks (buffer-file-name)
      ((lambda (new-heading)
         (if (not (string= new-heading current-heading))
             (progn
               (setq block-counter 1)
               (setq current-heading new-heading))
           (setq block-counter (+ 1 block-counter))))
       (replace-regexp-in-string "[ \t]" "-"
                                 (condition-case nil
                                     (or (nth 4 (org-heading-components))
                                         "(dummy for heading without text)")
                                   (error (buffer-file-name)))))
      (let* ((start-line (save-restriction (widen)
                                           (+ 1 (line-number-at-pos (point)))))
             (file (buffer-file-name))
             (info (org-babel-get-src-block-info 'light))
             (src-lang (nth 0 info)))
        (unless (or (string= (cdr (assoc :tangle (nth 2 info))) "no")
                    (null (intersection (mapcar 'intern org-babel-tags)
                                        (save-excursion
                                          (org-back-to-heading)
                                          (mapcar 'intern (org-get-tags))))))

                    (unless (and language (not (string= language src-lang)))
                      (let* ((info (org-babel-get-src-block-info))
                             (params (nth 2 info))
                             (extra (nth 3 info))
                             (cref-fmt (or (and (string-match "-l \"\\(.+\\)\"" extra)
                                                (match-string 1 extra))
                                           org-coderef-label-format))
                             (link ((lambda (link)
                                      (and (string-match org-bracket-link-regexp link)
                                           (match-string 1 link)))
                                    (org-no-properties
                                     (org-store-link nil))))
                             (source-name
                              (intern (or (nth 4 info)
                                          (format "%s:%d"
                                                  current-heading block-counter))))
                             (expand-cmd
                              (intern (concat "org-babel-expand-body:" src-lang)))
                             (assignments-cmd
                              (intern (concat "org-babel-variable-assignments:" src-lang)))
                             (body
                              ((lambda (body) ;; run the tangle-body-hook
                                 (with-temp-buffer
                                   (insert body)
                                   (when (string-match "-r" extra)
                                     (goto-char (point-min))
                                     (while (re-search-forward
                                             (replace-regexp-in-string "%s" ".+" cref-fmt) nil t)
                                       (replace-match "")))
                                   (run-hooks 'org-babel-tangle-body-hook)
                                   (buffer-string)))
                               ((lambda (body) ;; expand the body in language specific manner
                                  (if (assoc :no-expand params)
                                      body
                                    (if (fboundp expand-cmd)
                                        (funcall expand-cmd body params)
                                      (org-babel-expand-body:generic
                                       body params
                                       (and (fboundp assignments-cmd)
                                            (funcall assignments-cmd params))))))
                                (if (org-babel-noweb-p params :tangle)
                                    (org-babel-expand-noweb-references info)
                                  (nth 1 info)))))
                             (comment
                              (when (or (string= "both" (cdr (assoc :comments params)))
                                        (string= "org" (cdr (assoc :comments params))))
                                ;; from the previous heading or code-block end
                                (funcall
                                 org-babel-process-comment-text
                                 (buffer-substring
                                  (max (condition-case nil
                                           (save-excursion
                                             (org-back-to-heading t)  ; sets match data
                                             (match-end 0))
                                         (error (point-min)))
                                       (save-excursion
                                         (if (re-search-backward
                                              org-babel-src-block-regexp nil t)
                                             (match-end 0)
                                           (point-min))))
                                  (point)))))
                             by-lang)
                        ;; add the spec for this block to blocks under it's language
                        (setq by-lang (cdr (assoc src-lang blocks)))
                        (setq blocks (delq (assoc src-lang blocks) blocks))
                        (setq blocks (cons
                                      (cons src-lang
                                            (cons (list start-line file link
                                                        source-name params body comment)
                                                  by-lang)) blocks)))))))
    ;; ensure blocks in the correct order
    (setq blocks
          (mapcar
           (lambda (by-lang) (cons (car by-lang) (reverse (cdr by-lang))))
           blocks))
blocks))
```

Comment: hey @mike, what version of orgmode did you based upon? I went to `ob-tangle` where the function is from, and both code and signature are different: signature `(defun org-babel-tangle-collect-blocks (&optional language tangle-file)`

Comment: @AdrieanKhisbe I'm using 7.9.3f

Comment: Okey dokey, so they might have refactor the whole function for major version 8. I dropped searching a way to achieve it for now since with `use-package` I have a workaround. Thanks still! :)

Comment: So I take it there is no ready-made way to get this same functionality in Org-mode 8.3.2?