# How to org-babel-tangle only one code block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm generating multiple files in one .org file, with multiple source code blocks. For example:

```org
#+begin_src rst :tangle file1.rst :noweb yes
<<file1>>
#+end_src

#+begin_src rst :tangle file2.rst :noweb yes
<<file2>>
#+end_src
```

Is there any way to only tangle one specific code block without changing the header options?

I'm generating these files for Sphinx and to reduce the compilation time I want to tangle only the file I'm currently working on.

It would be great if there is a command such as `org-babel-tangle-current-block` - is there any way to do this?

(This is a related question to [Orgmode: how to filter the blocks to be tangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709914/orgmode-how-to-filter-the-blocks-to-be-tangle))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is possible by calling `org-babel-tangle` with a prefix argument.

So `C-u C-c C-v t` should do what you want.

From the docstring:

> With one universal prefix argument, only tangle the block at point.
>   When two universal prefix arguments, only tangle blocks for the tangle
>   file of the block at point.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case that someone is interested in binding a key to this - my init file includes the following:

```
(defun org-babel-tangle-block()
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-prefix-arg '(4)))
     (call-interactively 'org-babel-tangle)
))

(eval-after-load "org"
  '(progn
     (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c b") 'org-babel-tangle-block)
))
```

and I can tangle the code block under the cursor with `C-c b`.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to print the name of the file that was just created instead of the .org file containing the source code block?

Answer (score 0):

In extension to the helpful answer of joon I would like to share this snippet:

```
(defun org-babel-tangle-from-edit-special ()
    (interactive)
    (org-edit-src-exit)
    (let ((current-prefix-arg '(4)))
      (call-interactively 'org-babel-tangle))
    (org-edit-special))
```

...which can be combined with a keybinding like...

```
(add-hook 'org-src-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
   (local-set-key [f9] 'org-babel-tangle-from-edit-special)))
```

It allows you to tangle a source block from within the `org-edit-special` mode (so, whenever you hit `C-c '`). This is what I was actually looking for when finding this post.